# How do I use drools in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, drools

I have an intellij project.
I would like to incorporate drools in it.
How do I do it?
How do I get started with learning drools in intelij environment.

Comment: Please check that "JBoss Drools support" plugin is enabled. It provides some basic features. Please vote for the related request for full support: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-24348

Comment: Thanks. How do I add the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to y.bedrov answer, to add "JBoss Drools Support" plugin:

Ctrl+Alt+S -> Plugins -> Copy paste name of plugin. It should be installed by default, make sure the check mark is enabled.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.But I meant how do I install it?

Comment: @Ayala if you see it when you search for it, it is already installed - just make sure you check the checkbox to enable it. I've added screenshot to answer.

Comment: Thanks. But it's not installed. The question is really, where do I get it so I can install it? I'm using community edition 2017.2

Comment: @Ayala aha, that's because that plugin is only part of IntelliJ Ultimate Edition. I don't think IntelliJ Community Edition provides any support for Drools.

Comment: I've ended up installing intelliJ. I'm trying to create a session in an existing maven project (not drools project),  but I get null when giving it some name [kContainer.newKieSession("log-perm-session")] , or an exception for no default session. What I want to do is let the session know which rule file applies. How can I do that?

Comment: @Ayala you would be better off asking this as a new question, as that problem is unrelated to original problem/question posted here.